# Would using Cherenkov radiation for lighting be feasible?

Tags: visible-light, cherenkov-radiation

Could [Cherenkov radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation) be used for general illumination, for example, to replace LEDs, light bulbs etc? I.e. are there, or could there be, methods to produce substantial amount visible light with Cherenkov radiation:

- using devices compact and cheap enough,
- safely and
- energy-efficiently

to actually make any sense? What other problems could there be for using Cherenkov radiation for this purpose?

Comment: Survival is required? :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interesting question!

Cherenkov radiation would definitely be inefficient for illumination.  You only get Cherenkov radiation from charged particles moving faster than the local speed of light in a medium.  If you have a transparent medium with index of refraction $n=2$ and you're sending fast electrons through it, you'll only get Cherenkov radiation while the electrons have $v>0.5c$, or $$\gamma > \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-0.5^2}} = 1.15.$$
Since the kinetic energy is $T = (\gamma-1)mc^2$, this means the first $79\,\mathrm{keV}$ of electron energy contributes absolutely nothing to the Cherenkov illumination.  Seems like a lot of energy to waste.

Furthermore Cherenkov radiation tends to be concentrated in the UV, so you'd need some scintillation process to convert the light to visible.

The most serious complaint to me is that if the transparent material is thin enough that most of the light escapes, it won't be thick enough to stop the radiation that's causing the Cherenkov emission in the first place.  I think it'd be hard to commercialize a product which involved either (a) a mass equivalent to many radiation lengths in water or (b) hard radiation leaking out into the illuminated area.

Comment: I guess I'll stick to using it as a swimming pool ornament, and use tritium radioluminescence for beta-decay based lighting.

Answer (score 5):

Quite aside from the issue of ionizing radiation, Cerenkov generating particles also lose energy by other processes and that ends up as heat.

Moreover, all the kinetic energy of the particles once they drop below the Cerenkov threshold is lost in non-optical channels (i.e. more heat).

So no, they could never be anywhere near as efficient as diode lighting.

---

On top of that the spectrum is really cool to look at, but not the one you want in a lamp: it's far too blue.

Comment: I would suggest to add that if you ever "see" Cherenkov radiation with your own eyes, it's about time to run for your life. ;-)

Comment: @CuriousOne That depends. For instance the Cerenkov glow from a water-moderated, fission reactor is not a sign of danger because by design the moderator absorbs essentially all the dose. And it's pretty.

Comment: I'm sure I remember hearing an anecdote (possibly apocryphal) of someone aligning a particle beam by observing the Cerenkov radiation *in* his own eyes, never mind just *with* them...

Comment: @SteveJessop Those were the days when (in the words of a nuclear physics professor I had) "Men were men and radiation didn't hurt you." It was also the time when you could ship a 2 Curie AmBe source in a cardboard box by US post.